# Map HTTP Handler to allow .dll

Tags: 2013, permissions, file-upload, iis, caching

I am trying to upload files to `SharePoint 2013` `Document Library` programatically using C# and `WebClient` class.

When the request to upload the data to certain path is made, and the file is e.g. a `*.txt` then on SharePoint, the file is either created or modified.
When such file is .dll, the request fails, even though, I removed .dll from the blocked files list and manually am able to upload such files.

In SharePoint 2010, this worked perfectly, now, IDK how to map such files and their extensions under SharePoint 2013.

I tried some things that I found on the web, but with time, I only am getting more and more confused and am not able to move on.

Can this be somehow turned on in configuration of SharePoint / IIS / ... just anywhere?

EDIT: edited, because initially, I thought that file cache was causing the problem, which, in fact, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

From the msdn:
**To add or remove blocked file types by using Central Administration**

1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials.
2. You must be a farm administrator on the server.
3. In Central Administration, click Security.
4. On the Security page, in the General Security section, click Define blocked file types.

Comment: This is what I have obviously already done. Because I am able to upload `.dll` manually. It only does not work programatically. Thanks though.